# yii2. query with like condition

Tags: yii

In my yii2 application i need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE first_name||' '||last_name ILIKE '%Nick%' ORDER BY "id";
```

This query gets customers with concatinated first_name and last_name like 'Nick'.

In my yii1 application I can use CDBCriteria next way:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->addSearchCondition(
            "first_name||' '||last_name",
            'Nick',
            true,
            'and',
            'ILIKE'
        );

$criteria->order = 't.id asc';
```

And this works fine.

In yii2 I tried:

```
$a = \common\models\Customer::find()
        ->filterWhere(['ILIKE', "first_name||' '||last_name", 'Nick'])
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all();
```

And got exception column does not exist, and sql was:

```
SELECT * FROM "customers" WHERE "first_name||' '||last_name" ILIKE '%Nick%' ORDER BY "id"
```

Using \yii\db\Expression doesnt change situation.

Comment: which database your are using?

Comment: it is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many ways to do it:

```
$customers = \common\models\Customer::find()
        ->select('*')
        ->where(['like','concat(first_name,\' \', last_name)','Nick N'])
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all();
```

Comment: if customer first_name is 'Nick' and last_name is 'Nick', and query line is 'Nick N' it does not work

Comment: I did not understand what you were asking before. The example works according to your case now, I have edited the example.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be for a while:

```
\common\models\Customer::find()
                ->where("first_name||' '||last_name ilike '%'||:query||'%'", [':query' => $name])
                ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])
                ->all()
```